# how we access list and other fields from view to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Below is my code but i am only getting table data in list form not other fields.
how i can get both list and other fields data in controller.
when i change save button type with 'submit' code provide me other fields instead of table data in list form. On other hand when i change save button type to 'button' code provide only table data instead of other fields.

please solve the given code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ClosingOfTruck", "TripManage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.TruckId" />

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Current Truck:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 adg" })
            <div class="col-md-6 adg">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.TruckNo" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Cash received from various points", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 adg" })
            <div class="col-md-6 adg">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="OpeningBalance" />
            </div>
        </div>

        //Table for expense should be here
        <div class="row" style="margin:0px;">
            <table id="tblCustomers" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:150px">Description</th>
                        <th style="width:150px">Amount</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtCountry" /></td>
                        <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        //end

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Received from driver", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 adg" })
            <div class="col-md-6 adg">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ReceivedFromDriver" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Pay to driver", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 adg" })
            <div class="col-md-6 adg">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="PayToDriver" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Closing balance", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5 adg" })
            <div class="col-md-6 adg">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ClosingBalance" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin:0px;">
            <input class="form-control" type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
@section Script{

<script type="text/javascript">
            $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
                //Reference the Name and Country TextBoxes.
                var txtName = $("#txtName");
                var txtCountry = $("#txtCountry");

                //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
                var tBody = $("#tblCustomers > TBODY")[0];

                //Add Row.
                var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

                //Add Name cell.
                var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
                cell.html(txtName.val());

                //Add Country cell.
                cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
                cell.html(txtCountry.val());

                //Add Button cell.
                cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
                var btnRemove = $("<input />");
                btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
                btnRemove.attr("onclick", "Remove(this);");
                btnRemove.val("Remove");
                cell.append(btnRemove);

                //Clear the TextBoxes.
                txtName.val("");
                txtCountry.val("");
            });

            function Remove(button) {
                //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
                var row = $(button).closest("TR");
                var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
                if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
                    //Get the reference of the Table.
                    var table = $("#tblCustomers")[0];

                    //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
                    table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
                }
            };

            $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
                //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
                var Exps = new Array();
                $("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var customer = {};
                    customer.Desc = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
                    customer.Amount = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                    Exps.push(customer);
                });

                //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(Exps),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are only populating your json array `Exps` with the table data:

```
var Exps = new Array();
$("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var customer = {};
    customer.Desc = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
    customer.Amount = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
    Exps.push(customer);
});
```

So without a full form submission, you will only post that data:

```
data: JSON.stringify(Exps),
```

And get:

```
[{"Desc":"Sandwich","Amount":"5"},{"Desc":"Drink","Amount":"2"}]
```

If you want to post the form inputs without submitting the form, you'll have to add them to the data object before making the ajax call. Perhaps like this (make sure to also add name attributes to all your inputs):

```
var Log = new Array();
var frmData = $(document).find('form').serializeArray();
$.each(frmData, function (idx) {
    Log.push({ [this.name]: this.value });
});
var Exps = new Array();
$("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var customer = {};
    customer.Desc = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
    customer.Amount = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
    Exps.push(customer);
});
Log.push(Exps);
```

And change your ajax data to:

```
data: JSON.stringify(Log),
```

To get the following object data posted:

```
[{"TruckId":"1"}
,{"OpeningBalance":"1"}
,{"ReceivedFromDriver":"1"}
,{"PayToDriver":"1"}
,{"ClosingBalance":"1"}
,[{"Desc":"Desc1","Amount":"1"},{"Desc":"Desc2","Amount":"1"}]]
```

If you don't need to post as json, you could also just add hidden inputs to your table cells with the appropriate names and values and retrieve all form data in your ajax call like this:

```
data: $form.serialize(),
```

Comment: Hi, acurtis i am facing errror on this line of code " Log.push({ [this.name]: this.value });" and error look like this "SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number"

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to replicate the error. What browser are you using? Did you try others?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer & Chrome.

Comment: Without seeing the surrounding code it's difficult to say. You could try manually adding each item to the object. For example, `Log.TruckNo = $('#TruckNo').val();`.